# plot matlab function handle that outputs vector

Tags: matlab, plot

So I have a matlab function I wrote that takes in a number and returns an array of numbers (transposed).  I need to plot this function.  I was trying to use fplot but it was giving me errors:

```
Error in fplot (line 105)
x = xmin+minstep; y(2,:) = feval(fun,x,args{4:end});
```

Am I using the wrong plot function?

the function solves an equation of motion problem.  I have this diff eq:

```
Mx'' + Cx'+ Kx = 0
```

where M, C, and K are 4x4 matrices and my function solves the general solution and outputs a vector of 4 values.

Comment: @Acorbe: I dont really want to post all of the code on here.  Basically, I have the diff eq Mx'' + Cx' + Kx = 0.  M, C, and K are all 4x4 matrices that I know the values of.  What I am doing is solving for x(t) which equals e^(lambda*t)*x where lambda is the eigenvalue and x is the eigenvector.  I pass into the function t and get out an array of 4 values

Comment: thats ok, the point is just how you implemented the function handle. What if you pass is an array of time instants? is your function handle able to deal with that? did you implement operations componentwise?

Comment: @Acorbe: My function just takes in one numerical value and spits out an array of answers.  I cannot give the function an array of t and have it output a matrix or something.

Comment: My first remark would be: Do you really want to plot a function, or do you just want to plot the vector that results from calling the function? In the second case you just need to use `plot` rather than `fplot`.

Comment: What matlab does is giving your function handle a vector of time input and expecting a matrix of output, if that doesn't happen, you likely have a problem.

Comment: BTW, help people helping you and try to accept answers you receive. If you don't like answers you get, probably something is wrong with your questions, thus improve them. The community here is great.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: I am not exactly sure I guess.  I have a 4-degree of freedom system and I have created my four equation of motions.  From that I have gotten 3 matrices M, C, and K.  I then need to plot the general solution, x(t) that equals the sum( exp(lambda*t)*x) for all eigenvalue-vector pairs.  I am a little unsure on what exactly I need to plot.  I tried just using plot but that did not work either because my function does not take in a vector

Comment: @Acorbe: yeah sorry, I sometimes forget to check the checkbox.  I am currently trying to change my code to work with an array as input

Comment: @Acorbe: So I switched my function to work with an array inputted and a matrix outputted.  I am still getting the same error

Comment: How did you call the plot function?

Comment: I got it to work with the plot function actually.  I changed around my method to accept a range of t values and then called the plot function instead of fplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by changing my function to accept an array of t values and then I used the plot function instead of fplot